# Unable to change docker daemon Root Dir

Tags: docker

I am running docker version 24.0.2 on ubuntu.

I'd like to change the location of data root.

I stopped docker service,

I added --data-root option to the systemd configuration file, and restart the service.

I moved /var/lib/docker to /var/lib/docker.old

I restart the docker service.

Everything works fine, service is running,  I can pull the image from docker hub, and I can use docker as usual.

The only thing is the Root Dir is not changed...

if I ran ´docker info´:   "Docker Root Dir" still points to "/var/lib/docker".

If I ran ´docker image inspect *image*´,  Data are under "/var/lib/docker/overlay2" folder.

The problem is I don't have /var/lib/docker folder at all, I have moved the folder to /var/lib/docker.old.

I've checked the size of the new data root folder,  and /var/lib/docker.old,  both have less than 1 MB data, which means no image are saved in these two folder.

any idea where is the data root of my docker daemon now?